# Why code stop working after os.system command?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, python-multithreading, os.system

I have this code:

```
import os
import threading

def push_repository():
    try:
       os.system('git add *')
       os.system('git commit -m "Automated commit"')
       os.system('git push')
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)

def commit_and_push_git_folders(path):

 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
     for dir in dirs:
         if dir == '.git':
             print(os.path.join(root, dir))
             os.chdir(os.path.join(root, dir, '..'))
             t = threading.Thread(target=push_repository)
             t.start()

commit_and_push_git_folders('.')
```

Everything work properly, except the fact, that it goes only in first folder in given path and than stop working.
If I remove `os.system`'s command in `push_repository` function and change it to `print(os.path.join(root, dir))` everything is work cool and it goes in every single dir.

I already try to use threads, don't use threads, use subproccess and it's still goes off when first repositories was pushed

The current output is something like:
`.\ANN-visualizer\.git`
`On branch main`
`Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.`
`nothing to commit, working tree clean`
`Everything up-to-date`

But I have a few more folders with .git folder that need to be pushed.

Comment: The working directory is not being set correctly after the os.chdir()

Comment: I suspect the concept of "current directory" is global and not per thread.

Comment: The working directory is per-process.

Comment: In any case, this question lacks basic info. Please extract and provide a [mcve]. In particular, this should answer whether it has anything to do with threads or not. Then, tell us what behaviour that code exhibits. "than stop working" is just your interpretation and nothing that people can work with. Maybe also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted above, I suspect that the "current directory" is a global variable rather than per thread.

You could try:

```
def push_repository(directory):
    try:
       os.system(f'git -C {directory} add *')
       os.system(f'git -C {directory} commit -m "Automated commit"')
       os.system(f'git -C {directory} push')
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)

def commit_and_push_git_folders(path):

 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
     for dir in dirs:
         if dir == '.git':
             print(os.path.join(root, dir))
             directory = os.path.join(root, dir, '..'))
             t = threading.Thread(target=push_repository, args=(directory,))
             t.start()
```